# Curiosity on function maxima

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I was recently working with an equation of the form:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{a+bx+c\sqrt{x}}
$$
And I realized that the maxima (only considering positive real numbers) would always be at the point where:
$$
x=\frac ab 
$$
This is straightforward to prove by finding where the first derivative equals 0. Given this 'easy' result, I tried to find the logic behind it, which should probably be something easy, but I do not find it (I'm evidently no expert in mathematics, just curious).

My question is, should it be evident that the function has a maxima at that point without having to calculate the derivative? In the case it should, could someone explain me the reasoning behind it?

Thank you in advance.
Kind regards,
J.

Comment: If your question is simply the logic behind setting the derivative equal to 0, that is because, if the derivative, at a given point, is positive, the function is increasing- we could get a larger value by increasing x a little so the given point is NOT a maximum.  Similarly, if the derivative at a give point is negative, the function is decreasing- we could get a larger value by decreasing x a little so the given point is NOT a maximum.  This says that in order to be a (local) maximum, the derivative must be 0.  The other way- that is the derivative is 0, the function has a maximum, is FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as:$$
\frac{1}{b\sqrt{x}+\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{x}}+c}
$$

Then by AM-GM:

$$
b\sqrt{x}+\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{x}} \ge 2 \sqrt{ab}
$$

Also by AM-GM, equality holds when $b\sqrt{x}=\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{x}} \iff x = \cfrac{a}{b}\,$, which thus gives the minimum of the denominator, which in turn gives the maximum of the fraction.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The above interpretes the `"only considering positive real numbers"` stated condition to mean that $a,b,c$ and $x$ are strictly positive numbers.

Comment: What happens if $0$ is in the domain of $f$? Any way, nice approach.

Comment: @Nil I took `only considering positive real numbers` to mean *strictly* positive.

Comment: Ahhh... Yes you are right. +!

Comment: What I particularly like in your approach is that the first line of equation emphasize the non-dependency of the solution on $c$.

Comment: @dxiv: But still you have the assumption $ab\ge 0$

Comment: @Nil Actually $ab \gt 0$, and $c \gt 0$ as well. I edited the answer to make that point clear.

Comment: Thank you! It is elegant and I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

The reciprocal function is

$$\frac a{\sqrt x}+b\sqrt x+c$$ and the position of its extrema is independent of $c$.

We can factor out $b$ and get

$$b\left(\frac ab\frac 1{\sqrt x}+\sqrt x\right)+c,$$ which shows that the position can only depend on $\dfrac ab$.

The term $\dfrac a{\sqrt x}$ is decreasing and $b\sqrt x$ is increasing, the extremum is achieved when their slopes are opposite, which occurs when 
$$\frac a{2x\sqrt x}=\frac b{2\sqrt x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

the first derivative is given by $$f'(x)=1/2\,{\frac {-bx+a}{ \left( a+bx+c\sqrt {x} \right) ^{2}\sqrt {x}}}$$ the searched extrema ( if they exist) are located at $$x=\frac{a}{b}$$

Comment: Also $x=0$ should be a suspicious extreme point.

Comment: OP explicitly asks for a solution without computing derivatives..